# Multithreading in Async

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

1. I have a class called "Class A"
   a) I have a button called verify
   b) onClick of verify i call auth.authenticate() which returns boolean
   c) upon true - i have to call an intent
2. the authenticate function is in another class (auth is a ref)
3. authenticate function is as follow ()

> boolean authenticate() {
>
> ```
>  new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {      
>
>     preExecute()
>     {
>        --starting a progress bar--
>     }
>     doInBackground(String )
>     {
>         ----  huge authentication code-----
>         ------ returns true or false -------isVerified
>
>     }
>     onPostExecute(String)
>     {
>             ---   dismiss progress bar-----------
>     }       
>     }.execute();
>     }
>
>   --------end of AsynTask block----
>
>   synchronized (this) {
>
>         try {
>             this.wait();
>         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>
> return isVerified; ---- this should return to MyClass - after async finishes
> ```

-- but this is returned before async completes.. actually it is correct - because these are thread-- runs parallel, so to make it work - i have waited till async to complete using that synchronized block -- but that will blocking my main thread - (also no progress bar)

I could call my next activity in post execute success - as i m making a library class..i think should not... please help

}

Answer (score 0):

You can override `onPostExecute()` and return your value from there, if the task was cancelled  it will not be called.

Comment: but Chis, meanwhile "return isVerified" will run irrespective of onPostExecute return..

Comment: The value returned from doInBackground() is passed in to onPostExecute() this is not directly seen by the rest of your code. See the documentation for AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

AsyncTasks are also threads. So you can make a new `AuthenticateAsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>` class for authentication and with overriding the `onPostExecute` method you can call a function with the parameter `isVerified`

For Ex:

```
boolean isVerified;

// Async Task
class AuthenticateAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Authentication
        isVerified = returningValue // set your isVerified variable
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // you can here call a function that indicates the authenticaion value is returned
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello Nafiz, thanks for looking into it... Instead of a class as you have written I have a anonymous class in a function called authenticate - authenticate will return true of false without waiting for that async to finish.. thats the problem.. i have synchroized wait on this - so that i can wait till async to finish.. but that will block my thread.

Comment: And what about calling that authenticate function inside the doInBackground() function? 
- Start authenticate AsyncTask
- Call authenticate function in doInBackground
- when the authenticate function returns, the asyncTask's onPostExecute method get called
- And you can wait till the asyncTask's onPostExecute() method gets executen.

Comment: what i am looking for is - how to wait for another thread(or async) to complete without blocking the UI thread.. this.wait() will block the thread..